# How do I create a table view hierarchy on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

How do I create a table view hierarchy on iOS?

I've seen some tutorials where a plist was used but they were rather vague.
I would like to create one with many levels including a detailed view at the end of the hierarchial chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's documentation on [TableViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html) is pretty informative.
Also, look at the drill down examples on the Apple website itself.

Comment: This is the example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416